# How to send data from multiple page forms to a single page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Help me out in this problem, I have designed a multiple html pages with forms and I have to send that form data into a single page like summary can anyone able to help me..??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions here. That said, you can use sessionStorage to keep the values until the last page

Comment: `<form action="yourfile.php" ...`

Comment: Or alternatively, you could place all of your forms into one page, each in its' own DIV and open one at a time.  When done and submit, all of the fields are there.